# Algebra with all modules non-rigid 2

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Given a finite dimensional connected algebra $A$ with $Ext^{1}(M,M) \neq 0$ for any non-projective and non-injective indecomposable module $M$, with the condition that at least  one such module exists.

1. Is $A$ selfinjective?
2. Is $A$ local?

(answer is no,see the answer by Jeremy Rickard)

Two other questions:

3. Is it local when it is selfinjective?
4. Is it selfinjective when it is local?

Comment: Same counterexample, just because for the path algebra of $A_2$ there are no non-projective non-injective modules?

Comment: Ok I added that at least one such module exists. So no hereditary algebras should work.

Comment: Is the title grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=kQ/\text{rad}(kQ)^2$, where $Q$ has two vertices, a loop at vertex $1$ and an arrow from vertex $1$ to vertex $2$. I think it has five indecomposable modules, all of which are either projective or injective apart from the simple $S_1$ at vertex $1$, and $\text{Ext}^1_A(S_1,S_1)\neq0$.

Comment: QPA confirms it. I leave the question open for 3. and 4.